# How to subset a dataframe based on columns that match another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create `results.interaction.subset` data frame by subsetting the columns of `results.interaction.model` with the `all.dnam` data frame.

There are 18 common columns in `results.interaction.model` and `all.dnam` data frames.

```
> which( colnames(results.interaction.model) %in% colnames(all.dnam) )
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 16 17 19 20 21
```

However, when I subset `results.interaction.model` based on the common columns, it only returns two columns.

```
results.interaction.subset <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(results.interaction.model[ which( colnames(results.interaction.model) %in% colnames(all.dnam) ), ])))
```

Data:

`results.interaction.model`

```
> dput(results.interaction.model[1:10])
structure(list(regionID = c("chr1:959207-959208", "chr1:959207-959208", 
"chr1:959207-959208", "chr1:959207-959208", "chr1:959207-959208", 
"chr1:1000481-1000482", "chr1:1116515-1116516", "chr1:1281750-1281751", 
"chr1:1282131-1282132", "chr1:1282131-1282132"), probeID = c("cg04485075", 
"cg04485075", "cg04485075", "cg04485075", "cg04485075", "cg00447632", 
"cg08881995", "cg06909630", "cg00825734", "cg00825734"), target_symbol = c("NOC2L", 
"NOC2L", "KLHL17", "KLHL17", "KLHL17", "ISG15", "C1orf159", "SCNN1D", 
"SCNN1D", "SCNN1D"), target = c("ENSG00000188976", "ENSG00000188976", 
"ENSG00000187961", "ENSG00000187961", "ENSG00000187961", "ENSG00000187608", 
"ENSG00000131591", "ENSG00000162572", "ENSG00000162572", "ENSG00000162572"
), TF_symbol = c("ELK4", "THAP1", "THAP1", "KLF5", "ETV5", "RELA", 
"KLF5", "PRDM1", "NFIC", "SNAI1"), TF = c("ENSG00000158711", 
"ENSG00000131931", "ENSG00000131931", "ENSG00000102554", "ENSG00000244405", 
"ENSG00000173039", "ENSG00000102554", "ENSG00000057657", "ENSG00000141905", 
"ENSG00000124216"), distance_region_target_tss = c(100, 100, 
-1375, -1375, -1375, -655, -153, 1313, 1694, 1694), target_region = c("chr1:944203-959309", 
"chr1:944203-959309", "chr1:960584-965719", "chr1:960584-965719", 
"chr1:960584-965719", "chr1:1001138-1014540", "chr1:1081818-1116361", 
"chr1:1280436-1292029", "chr1:1280436-1292029", "chr1:1280436-1292029"
), met.IQR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RLM_DNAmGroup_pvalue = c(0.00533045223821893, 
0.269498808026373, 0.106850951179939, 0.737849880311862, 0.0230970250677056, 
0.0679623870851049, 0.0038827086445532, 0.721008613093728, 0.0774394444145674, 
0.000612845575647114), RLM_DNAmGroup_fdr = c(0.0533045223821893, 
0.336873510032967, 0.213701902359879, 0.779545220292938, 0.0769900835590187, 
0.0679623870851049, 0.0038827086445532, 0.721008613093728, 0.0774394444145674, 
0.00122569115129423), RLM_TF_pvalue = c(0.000240408628747302, 
0.00967551181571213, 1.49822287909274e-09, 0.000292719662255525, 
0.00618840879521954, 0.00179253431503446, 0.452246528946535, 
0.00234418657279578, 1.7960719511656e-06, 0.517725724264309), 
    RLM_TF_fdr = c(0.000975732207518417, 0.0193510236314243, 
    1.49822287909274e-08, 0.000975732207518417, 0.0154710219880488, 
    0.00179253431503446, 0.452246528946535, 0.00234418657279578, 
    3.5921439023312e-06, 0.517725724264309), `RLM_DNAmGroup:TF_pvalue` = c(0.0477235974653309, 
    0.446924723241917, 0.18614609117704, 0.667529698315539, 0.0785854522508826, 
    0.0525551281674801, 0.000669386554848383, 0.662460106324088, 
    0.00893706117486159, 0.610417816470398), `RLM_DNAmGroup:TF_fdr` = c(0.324105485296749, 
    0.698683488173363, 0.4653652279426, 0.698683488173363, 0.324105485296749, 
    0.0525551281674801, 0.000669386554848383, 0.662460106324088, 
    0.0178741223497232, 0.610417816470398), RLM_DNAmGroup_estimate = c(-1.37422624654216, 
    -1.19017301712196, -4.03293591748801, -0.35645377491457, 
    -3.8339403287343, 12.0286802799871, -2.78005839590399, -0.655219229413673, 
    3.59394098562824, -3.55478802638191), RLM_TF_estimate = c(-0.190759510600258, 
    -0.232045171131347, -1.33229518558913, 0.298181138499663, 
    -0.371852537012647, 1.47733874118035, -0.0562213201987235, 
    -0.468753054985941, -0.589036223592858, 0.0879194889561481
    ), `RLM_DNAmGroup:TF_estimate` = c(0.142736765645357, 0.110237497587508, 
    0.444463040091438, -0.0556779464074764, 0.33964931110994, 
    -1.16778588303793, 0.402784394412433, 0.102709381127899, 
    -0.557414220417646, 0.0965723392687151), Model.quantile = c("Robust Linear Model", 
    "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", 
    "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", 
    "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model"
    ), Target_gene_DNAm_high_vs_Target_gene_DNAm_low_wilcoxon_pvalue = c(2.1412139799407e-08, 
    2.1412139799407e-08, 1.15677939082746e-06, 1.15677939082746e-06, 
    1.15677939082746e-06, 0.000615392235920677, 0.00298164989940998, 
    0.00366189819005736, 1.54702834819721e-12, 1.54702834819721e-12
    ), TF_DNAm_high_vs_TF_DNAm_low_wilcoxon_pvalue = c(0.918438542048966, 
    0.0464669455108157, 0.0464669455108157, 0.0697343857747443, 
    0.720893397374373, 0.519583665503581, 0.00993093689687174, 
    5.3480514392441e-16, 4.20885311279533e-08, 1.17793835284239e-10
    ), `% of target genes not expressed in DNAm_low and DNAm_high` = c("0 %", 
    "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000029cc3feb5c0>)
```

`all.dnam`

```
> dput(all.dnam[1:10])
structure(list(regionID = c("chr11:73647473-73647474", "chr12:26834132-26834133", 
"chr10:49761673-49761674", "chr5:40841488-40841489", "chr16:68236355-68236356", 
"chr5:103563028-103563029"), probeID = c("cg06008062", "cg07645296", 
"cg02430797", "cg05981038", "cg04328477", "cg07655627"), target_symbol = c("PLEKHB1", 
"ITPR2", "OGDHL", "CARD6", "ESRP2", "NUDT12"), target = c("ENSG00000021300", 
"ENSG00000123104", "ENSG00000197444", "ENSG00000132357", "ENSG00000103067", 
"ENSG00000112874"), TF_symbol = c("VDR", "FOXN3", "RUNX2", "SOX9", 
"KLF5", "NFATC2"), TF = c("ENSG00000111424", "ENSG00000053254", 
"ENSG00000124813", "ENSG00000125398", "ENSG00000102554", "ENSG00000101096"
), distance_region_target_tss = c(1294L, -937L, 704L, 179L, 1745L, 
-237L), target_region = c("chr11:73646178-73662819", "chr12:26335352-26833194", 
"chr10:49734641-49762379", "chr5:40841308-40860175", "chr16:68229033-68238102", 
"chr5:103548855-103562790"), met.IQR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), RLM_DNAmGroup_pvalue = c(0.0611683203352245, 0.37071989654808, 
0.0031516822161683, 0.0047522559428827, 0.581928610825936, 0.0010290648987458
)), row.names = c(62L, 73L, 56L, 8L, 115L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job. Note I changed the name of `results.interaction.model` to `d` and used `d_sub` rather than `results.interaction.subset`, becuase they are shorter and easier to read.

```
d <- results.interaction.model
d_sub <- d[, colnames(d) %in% colnames(all.dnam)]
```

You can check that d_sub has the correct names with:

```
dplyr::glimpse(d_sub)
```

```
Rows: 10
Columns: 10
$ regionID                   <chr> "chr1:959207-959208", "chr1:959207-959208", "ch…
$ probeID                    <chr> "cg04485075", "cg04485075", "cg04485075", "cg04…
$ target_symbol              <chr> "NOC2L", "NOC2L", "KLHL17", "KLHL17", "KLHL17",…
$ target                     <chr> "ENSG00000188976", "ENSG00000188976", "ENSG0000…
$ TF_symbol                  <chr> "ELK4", "THAP1", "THAP1", "KLF5", "ETV5", "RELA…
$ TF                         <chr> "ENSG00000158711", "ENSG00000131931", "ENSG0000…
$ distance_region_target_tss <dbl> 100, 100, -1375, -1375, -1375, -655, -153, 1313…
$ target_region              <chr> "chr1:944203-959309", "chr1:944203-959309", "ch…
$ met.IQR                    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ RLM_DNAmGroup_pvalue       <dbl> 0.0053304522, 0.2694988080, 0.1068509512, 0.737…
```

Comment: It returns a logical vector. How do I retain it as a dataframe?

Comment: `colnames(d) %in% colnames(all.dnam)` will return a logical vector. But, as i do above, you then use that logical vector to subset the columns of the dataframe with `d[, colnames(d) %in% colnames(all.dnam)]`

Comment: `d[, colnames(d) %in% colnames(all.dnam)] `still returns a logical vector

Comment: That must mean that `d` is a logical vector. Check that d is the data frame. If you run the code like this it should work, sorry can't be of any further help: ```d <- results.interaction.model;
d_sub <- d[, colnames(d) %in% colnames(all.dnam)]```

Comment: `d` is `[1] "data.table" "data.frame"`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the problem is, it runs perfectly fine on my machine.